# How are PHP releases numbered?

Tags: php

I am looking to upgrade WordPress on my server. WordPress 3.2 [requires PHP 5.2.4 or greater](http://wordpress.org/about/requirements/). My server is running PHP 5.2.17. Looking at the [release history on php.net](http://php.net/releases/index.php), I see that:

1. 5.2.4 was released 30 August 2007
2. There is no listing for 5.2.17
3. 5.2.16 was released 16 December 2010
4. Release order with a few versions goes: 5.2.13, 5.3.2, 5.2.14, 5.3.3, 5.2.15

Two questions:

- What is the logic of this numbering system?
- Is PHP 5.2.17 "greater" than 5.2.4?

Comment: 5.2.17 > 5.2.4? `version_compare()` returns true: http://codepad.org/2Q5b2Vzo

Comment: There are two branches 5.2 and 5.3. The title of the page you linked to is *Unsupported Historical Releases*. The latest versions are listed here: http://www.php.net/downloads.php. 5.2.17 is the latest version for the 5.2 branch.

Comment: It's not all that obvious: 2.17 < 2.4

Comment: @Madmartigan yeah, but it's x.y.z and not just y.z (a float) ;)

Comment: @Gordon: Yeah I know, I'm just trying to highlight how it can be misunderstood. I thought your comment was a little bit rude.

Comment: The [PHP Changelog (for example for version 5)](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php) has all the release dates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short,

- `5.3.x > 5.2.y`
- `5.2.(z+1) > 5.2.(z)`

You can also expect periodical maintenance releases on both 5.2 and 5.3. This is why you can see `5.2.x` releases appearing after `5.3.y` releases.

Hope that helps,

Comment: And to further clear the confusion, PHP (and most other large software projects) has several branches being developed "in parallel". The 5.2.x branch is the "old branch". They're not actively developing it, but there are critical bugfixes now and then. 5.3.x is the current version. It gets mostly bugfixes, but now and then there are new things too. 5.4.x is also in the making, but not yet ready for public consumption.

Comment: And so it comes to the realization that dates aren't really a reliable way to compare "what is newer". :)

Answer (score 2):

The last number in the version string (so `4`, `16`, etc) is for minor releases such as bugfixes or quick security patches. The middle number is for more significant releases containing a lot of new functionality, fixed bugs, security patches and the like. The remaining `5` is for massive releases that may have been the result of an entire rewrite (unlikely), or something of that magnitude.

You are correct in saying PHP 5.2.17 is newer than 5.2.4; common sense dictates that `17` is greater than `4`. You'll be fine if you install Wordpress on a 5.2.17 installation.

Comment: Note that there are also some minor incompatibilities between the significant (second-digit) releases. Major releases (first-digit) usually bring lots of incompatibilities, and most PHP code will probably need to be retouched to get it working under a newer version. Though they do try to be as compatible as possible.

Comment: Thanks @Vilx- I forgot to mention that!

Answer (score 2):

The most recent versions in the 5.2 and 5.3 branches are listed on http://www.php.net/downloads.php That's where your 5.2.17 is listed. PHP uses the common ["change significance"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning#Change_significance) system: [major].[minor].[maintenance]. More specifically, PHP has its own version comparison function: [version_compare()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php)

It works like this:

> The function first replaces _, - and + with a dot . in the version strings and also inserts dots . before and after any non number so that for example '4.3.2RC1' becomes '4.3.2.RC.1'. Then it splits the results like if you were using explode('.', $ver). Then it compares the parts starting from left to right. If a part contains special version strings these are handled in the following order: any string not found in this list < dev < alpha = a < beta = b < RC = rc < # < pl = p. This way not only versions with different levels like '4.1' and '4.1.2' can be compared but also any PHP specific version containing development state.